# Vb.net: Programm that is able to controll services

Tags: database, vb.net, service

at the place where im working, there is an Local Server. On that server are running 2 different Databases, every night there im doing a backup of it. First i always have to shut down the database service.

What I want to do is create a program that will shut down the 2 services at 00:00 AM and lunch it again at 06:00 AM. I tried

```
 Dim service As ServiceController = New ServiceController("MSSQLSERVER")
    If ((service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) Or
        (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending))) Then
        service.Start()
```

But it doesn't work
Any Ideas what could I use?

Comment: Your really best approach is to use powershell. Lots of code out there. You can start here. https://4sysops.com/archives/managing-services-the-powershell-way-part-3/

Comment: Ok, I will take a look

Comment: What error message do you get?, and do you have enough rights?

Comment: "Could not open Service"
Yes, it was lunched as Administrator